# How do I override markdown rules in Prettier?

Tags: markdown, prettier

I use the [Prettier extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) for VSCode. I've managed to set up a base project that extends ESLint such that I can format my JavaScript syntax automatically on save, following the [standard rules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-standard).

Is there a way to do the same for markdown? I'd like to leverage [markdownlint](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint) rules or similar since Prettier forces numbered lists as:

```
<!-- Prettier rules -->
1. This is
1. A numbered
1. List
```

But I prefer manual numbering like so:

```
<!-- My rules -->
1. This is
2. A manual 
3. List
```

Answer (score 9):

Not exactly what you asked for, but you can deactivate Prettier for MarkDown files by creating a file named `.prettierignore` in the project root, in which you write `*.md`.

See [Prettier documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html) for details.

Comment: This helps to me.

Answer (score 7):

Prettier does not enforce numbered lists as:

```
1. first
1. second
1. third
```

See this on Prettier's playground: [link](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEBGAdAAgJbwLYA6UGO+RATFrnIVAMxVlREnW2Wk1EOe0AsjGiAA0ICAAcY2aAGdkoAIYAnJRADuABWUI5KBQDcI2ACYiQCmTGQAzBQBsZcUQCMlCsAGs4MAMrj32FAA5sgwSgCuTiDGEGA29o6igY5KMBpuQXgK8Q5RAFYyAB4AQm6e3j4KeHAAMoFwOYli4TDiLeSNUf5KKcggWUoeMWpQZuJKgTAA6iYwABbIABwADKLjEI5TbuJ943Ap+g2iSnAAjuHYJ+kKmdlItrmijnjYoRFRMoFBdnAAiuEQeCdUQwBTOGbGebIcggtzYOxfADCEDwWT6UGgRxA4UcABUwboHo4AL7EoA)

It will detect if your 2nd item is also `1.` and format the list like that, otherwise, it will format with incrementing numbers.

There's no way to override Prettier's rules, can only change the options passed, but for markdown only the `--prose-wrap` option is available. You are free to run Prettier and then run `markdownlint` later to adjust to your preferences, if you so desire, just like one would do with ESLint.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`eslint-plugin-markdownlint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-markdownlint) to lint your markdown files.

With settings to override rules for `.md` files it will take precedence over prettier:

```json
// .eslintrc
{
  "overrides": [{
    "files": ["*.md"],
    "parser": "eslint-plugin-markdownlint/parser",
    "extends": ["plugin:markdownlint/recommended"]
  }]
}
```

Note: I'm author of this plugin, but this uses [markdownlint](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint) library to lint files.